# How to design reasonable database?

Tags: database, firebase

I'm very new about relational-database and wonder how should I design my database generally like case as follows:

**Conditions**

1. There are **five articles** in my apps and those are able to be bookmarked by users and also those articles are defined as uniqe `articleid` like `a,b,c,d,e`.
2. There are **three users** in my apps and users are defined as uniqe `userid` like `1,2,3`.
3. Finally, I should manage or control the relations of which articles are bookmarked by specified users.

I leard that I can choose following ways technically but wonder which shuold be choosed for good paerformance and maitainance **genellary**.

■ case1
Managing those relations in single table.
allmixedtable

| userid | articleid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | d |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | e |

■ case2
Creating usertable and managing those relations in several tables respectivley.

user1table

| articleid |
| --- |
| a |
| c |
| d |

user2table

| articleid |
| --- |
| d |

user3table

| articleid |
| --- |
| b |
| e |

■ case3
Managing those relations in sigle table as array

| userid | articleid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[a,c,d]` |
| 2 | `[d]` |
| 3 | `[b,e]` |

I feel case1 is the best but in terms of performance of serching certin records using `userid key` others could be better.
I understand that it depends on a situation but want to know as general thinking.
I'll do appreciate your helpful comment, thank you!

Comment: Firebase has 2 databases, which one are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I understood that it means if I'm gonna use realtime or firestore, right?
So far, I'm gonna use firestore database.

Comment: So it's about a nonrelational database, right? In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo
Thanks for your comment and I figured out that this (firebase) is about non-relational database. I could not understand the point "What are those queries?" mentioned above.
"Select articleid from table where userid = 1" 
Is this kind of expression could be answer against your question ?

Comment: Which database from Firebase are you willing to use? And yes, show the queries you intend to perfrom.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks again and Im willing to use firestore DB and simply query shown above is intend to perform. Im sorry that I have experience only about mysql and never about firebase. And wonder if this kind of query is adoptable in firebase or not..

Comment: There are no joins in NoSQL databases. That's why I was asking what queries you want to perform. You can explain that as simple as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248045/discussion-between-sugiuray-and-alex-mamo).